# Error on trying to do an automate email scheduler

Tags: python, time, smtp, scheduler

so i'm trying to create a python tool to do an email automation using library scheduler and timer, to schedule the email sharing. but after running i got this error instead.

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

The code that i use is pretty long, so here's what the shoter version look like.

Here is the code that i use the short version since it's too long if i were to post it here.

```
import time
import schedule

def AutoEmailSending():
    
    @repeat(every(30).seconds)
    def Email CreationSending():

        ..........

        def zipdir(path, ziph):
           for root,dirs, files in os.walk(path):
               .......

               for file in files:
                   ......

        with zipfile.ZipFie('file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zipf:
             zipdir('directory', zipf)

        ..........
        smtpObj.quit
        directory = "LocationDir"
        location = ""
        path = os.path.join(location, directory)
        shutil.rmtree(path)

    schedule.every().second.do(EmailCreationSending)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

AutoEmailSending()
```

The code for the email SMTP with file attachment works, but i think my code for the time scheduler might possibly be wrong. Any suggestion on how to fix it?

Thanks for the help!